# Creating a consistent schema with mongodb and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I still can't wrap my head around the idea of NoSQL databases like mongodb.
I'm creating a project with this different set of Mongoose models:

Department Model:

```
var DepartmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  categories : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Category', required : true}]
});
```

Category Model:

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  icon : String,
  products : [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Category'}]
});
```

Product Model:

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  imgUrl : String,
  category : {
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Category', required : true
  }
});
```

User Model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { 
    type: String
  },
  requests : [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Request'}],

});
```

Request Model:

```
var RequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  user : {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User', required : true},
  product : {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Product', required : true},
  fulfilled : { type : Boolean, default : false }
});
```

Basically a Department can have multiple categories, a category can have multiple products and a user can create requests, and requests are pretty much links between a product and a user.

I know this is a more relational approach so I don't really care about updating the referenced schemas, the problem comes when I need to delete a category for example, products would still exist so I would have to manually delete every product (and therefore requests) for that specific category.

Now if I try an embedded approach in which I put my data as an entire object, containing departments, categories and products, that's not a problem because I can just delete a part of the array, the problem comes when I create a request, I would have to copy the product from the Department object into a request, then, later on, if I update the product inside that object, how would I keep track of the updates and the requests that I've already saved in other documents?

If it helps, I'm using a yeoman generator (angular-fullstack) to generate the model,controller,routes for an endpoint or entity.

Thank you.